# Switch Statement with multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement that actually works fine.

```
          for (n = 0; n < 10; n++){

          switch(results[r][n]){

           case 0:
           result[r][n] = "FAIL";
           break;

           case 1:
           result[r][n] = "PASS";
           break;

           default:
           break;

        }
      }
```

my question is WHY does this work, is it supposed to work or is there a much better way of doing this?
Is this how you are supposed to implement multi-dimensional arrays within a switch?
(r = 0 or 1)
How does the compiler know whether case 0: refers to r or n?

Comment: There's not enough code here to know exactly what's going on, but if I were to guess, I'd say that `results` is an ordinary, two-dimensional array of `int`s, and that `results[r][n]` addresses a single `int`.  Don't know why you'd think that wouldn't work.

Comment: Note that `result` is a different array than `results`.

Comment: Thats correct, I am just trying to figure out how the compiler knows that case 0: and case 1: refers to the [r] component of the array and not [n]

Comment: `case 0` refers to `results[r][n]`, not `r` or `n`. The values after `case` are matched to the value in the `switch()`.

Comment: You need to show more code context. Please add a [mcve] we don't know what `results`  or `result` types are.

Comment: ***1) How does the compiler know whether case 0: refers to r or n?*** It does not refer to r or n.

Answer (score 2):

`case 0` refers to `results[r][n]`, not `r` or `n`. The values after `case` are matched to the value of the expression in the `switch()`.

Look at a [tutorial on switch-case](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm#:%7E:text=Advertisements,is%20checked%20for%20each%20case.)

Your switch statement

```
switch(results[r][n]) {

case 0:
    result[r][n] = "FAIL";
    break;

case 1:
    result[r][n] = "PASS";
    break;

default:
    break;

}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (results[r][n] == 0)
    result[r][n] = "FAIL";

else if (results[r][n] == 1)
    result[r][n] = "PASS";

else
    // do nothing
```

To anyone who was confused by the assignment of a string to something that should be an integer array, `results` is the integer[] array, `result` is a different variable that's a string[] array. As Robert notes below in the comments, a better naming system seems to be in order here.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I am still fairly new to  2D arrays. Of course the switch is determining if the memory location of result[r][n] contains a 0 or a 1

Comment: @Joe: *Note that `result` is a different array than `results`.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I am aware of this. I should have said if location results[r][n] contains 0 or 1

Comment: Better array naming would seem to be in order here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I agree!

Comment: @RobertHarvey good point. I'm going to add it to my answer, because I spent some time wondering how that would even be possible before realizing that they were two different names